# What's the next step to solve this Nonogram?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, nonogram

I've gotten myself stuck in this Nonogram level using the logic I'm familiar with (filling in our crossing out boxes that will *always* be filled in or empty no matter how you fill in the grid). And until now, I've been able to finish every other level using only that basic rule.

[image: Half-finished Nonogram Level 50 from the mobile game Meow Tower]

Can I proceed from here without guessing, hints, or bruteforce?

The game it's from is Meow Tower (hard level #50), and in the 456 nonograms I've completed so far (407 easy, 49 hard), every puzzle has been solvable using basic logic, and only have one solution. And if you make a mistake, you instantly get corrected, so I don't think it's a problem with the generation or a bug in the game.

Comment: It looks to me as if the game is giving you more information than you would have solving on paper, by telling you _which_ things in a given row/column you have successfully marked. If I'm understanding that correctly, then e.g. the two "1 2" columns near the middle -- where it's told you that the squares you've shaded are "1" rather than "2" -- let you fill in a number of squares you haven't yet.

Comment: Has a useful answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Start by looking at the two filled cells you have in column 13 (labelled **A** in the picture below).
>  It doesn't matter whether those are part of the 2 or the 4 in that column, the cell below (R12C13, labelled **B**) must be filled.
>  Now row 12 only has two single filled cells, so the adjacent cells must be empty (labelled **C**).
>  And that forces most of the 9-cell block in column 14 (labelled **D**).
>  [image]

> And from there filling in the obvious forced moves gets you to the following position.
>  [image]

> From there, the 3 in the bottom row only has one place to go.
>  And that forces the 8 in column 8.
>  And I'll stop there as the question only asked for a next step, not a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

note that black mean filled, blue means empty.

if you think as below;

> [image]

the rest will fail as below;

> [image]

so we know that, it should be like that below;

> [image]

the rest becomes easier I think;

> [image]

Comment: I think this ties in nicely with Gareth's comment under the question. The app is also giving a clue that the first option is not correct because the "2" in the "2 4" column is not highlighted in blue.